# getting a particular svg polygon in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, svg

I have a bunch of svg polygons on my web page, each with an id that corresponds to the name of county in my state, for example:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#DCDDDE" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
190.41,192.082 194.273,187.422 204.273,185.109 207.954,184.596 210.917,181.566 211.49,181.674 213.694,182.688 215.108,184.742 
217.418,185.174 217.885,185.863 221.539,191.93 220.957,191.818 220.85,192.395 221.32,193.08 221.214,193.656 220.42,194.705 
220.313,195.283 220.778,195.973 220.674,196.545 221.145,197.238 221.722,197.344 221.615,197.918 222.086,198.605 220.71,199.549 
219.918,200.592 219.341,200.48 219.454,209.477 206.198,209.986 191.213,210.172 190.994,201.764 " id="Adams"/>
...
</svg>
```

I also have an json object that holds data for about county. I want to call each polygon by name in jquery. This should be an easy thing, but I'm having trouble. I've been using:

```
$('polygon#'+ obj[i].county ).css('fill', 'blue');
```

But this isn't working.

I tried:

```
$('#'+ obj[i].county ).css('fill', 'blue');
```

Also didn't work.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please?

**UPDATE**

If I say:

```
$('#Adams' ).css('fill', 'blue');
```

...it works. But if I say:

```
$('#'+ obj[i].county ).css('fill', 'blue');
```

...it doesn't.

Comment: Works for me when I test with your code. Where is your script located? Are you calling it on page load or when the user clicks, etc?

Comment: And where on the page is it? I recently ran into a problem with jquery's ready function in IE because I included my script at the top of the page, but jquery fired the ready event before the dom was completely loaded. You may have to change to $(window).load if this is the case. Try putting your code at the bottom of your page and see what happens. Otherwise, you should post more (or a fiddle) so that we can get a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a `<svg>` issue but a `id=xxx` matching issue. Two liner to capitalize it:-

```
var c = 'COUNTY'; // ie: obj[i].county
var cap = c[0].toUpperCase() + c.slice(1).toLowerCase();
```

Note: some prefer `.substring(1)` instead of `.slice(1)`

Answer (score 0):

My problem wasn't indicating the county. It was that the county name as it came out of the data was in all capital letters, while the polygon IDs just had the first letter capitalized.